# How to stop share section on toolbar from displaying default app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

I'm looking for a way to stop my share button from changing after first use. After first use share "section" on toolbar starts dispaying default app icon next to share icon. Below is screenshot showing the transition.

[image]

My menu_main.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/create_order_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        />

</menu>
```

And my Kotlin code:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareActionProvider = MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem) as 
        ShareActionProvider
        setShareActionIntent("Want to join me for pizza?")
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

private fun setShareActionIntent(text: String){
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.type = "text/plain"
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
        shareActionProvider!!.setShareIntent(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can save a **Boolean** Value in **sharedPreference**
- In the **onCreate** of Your first launching Activity you check the **sharedPreference** is null or false
- If null you will show the first time portion code
- And You have to set it to (**boolean** firstRun=*false*) 
  Then After all the time your app will get false and will show next What you need.